# RethinkDB filter on nested objects

Tags: json, filter, rethinkdb

I need the solution for filter data by nested objects.
So, this is my JSON data:

```
{
"create_datetime": 1431000977 ,
"creator": {
    "company": {
        "id": 0 ,
        "name": "Some name"
    } ,
    "manager": {
        "id": 0 ,
        "name": ""
    }
} ,
"finished_datetime": 1431615600 ,
"id": "00949296-cbea-4d4a-a780-7c8d918a7fd6" ,
"participants": [ ],
"status": "created" ,
"tender_categories": [
    1285
] ,
"views": [ ]
},
{
"create_datetime": 1431416740 ,
"creator": {
    "company": {
        "id": 70922233 ,
        "name": "Some company name"
    } ,
    "manager": {
        "id": 1003546168 ,
        "name": "Some manager name"
    }
} ,
"finished_datetime": 1432857600 ,
"id": "28e0936b-84e0-4ffc-9ad1-78a1d34e9033" ,
"participants": {
    "788190": {
        "creator": {
            "company": {
                "id": 788190 ,
                "name": "Company name"
            } ,
            "manager": {
                "id": 1003546168 ,
                "name": "Manager Name"
            }
        } ,
        "dt_applied": 1431416778 ,
        "viewed": false
    }
} ,
"status": "created" ,
"tender_categories": [1303] ,
"views": [788190]
}
```

I need select one record from this JSON where we have participants, that not viewed. I wrote a lot of code, but one one work.

```
r.db('test').table('tenders').filter(function(tender) {
  return tender('participants').coerceTo('array').map(function(participant) {
    return participant('viewed').eq(false)
  });
});
```

and

```
r.db('pm').table('b2b_tenders').map(function(tender) {
  return tender('participants').filter(function(key) {
    return tender(key)('viewed').eq(false)
  });
});
```

and so one. Help pls some one.

Answer (score 7):

Any type of filtering with nested objects is perfectly doable. In your case, it seems you want all documents, where all participants have the property `view` set to false.

Here's a very long, yet complete and safe way of checking for something like this:

```
r.db('test').table('tenders')
  // Only get all documents with `participants` property
  .hasFields('participants')
  // Only get documents where the `participants` property is an object
  .filter(function (row) {
    return row('participants').typeOf().eq('OBJECT')
  })
  // Only get documents where all participants have a `viewed` property
  .filter(function (row) {
    return row('participants').coerceTo('array')
      .map(function (row) {
        return row(1).hasFields('viewed')
      })
      .distinct()
      .eq([true])
  })
  // Only get documents where all participants have a `viewed` property set to `true`
  .filter(function (row) {
    return row('participants').coerceTo('array')
      .map(function (row) {
         return row(1)('viewed').eq(false)
      })
      .distinct()
      .eq([true])
  })
```

You can probably take out or change parts of this query to fit your needs and depending on how much you know about the documents that are coming in. But, this query shows how to deal with nested properties.